# Applying colour over the image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

In my Android APP, I have some alphabet (Say A.. as mentioned in the below image). This is going to be in a Layout. When the user touch / trace over the image the image has to be colored in RED. In other words the color of the image has to changed to RED color.

Any suggestion on how to achieve this will be a great help. Thanks in Advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In side the touch listener use the following code

```
// Get the Image container object
ImageView imgStatus = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgInfoIcon);

// Load the icon as drawable object
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details);

// Get the color of the icon depending on system state
int iconColor = android.graphics.Color.BLACK
if (systemState == Status.ERROR)
    iconColor = android.graphics.Color.RED
else if (systemState == Status.WARNING)
    iconColor = android.graphics.Color.YELLOW
else if (systemState == Status.OK)
    iconColor = android.graphics.Color.GREEN

// Set the correct new color
d.setColorFilter( iconColor, Mode.MULTIPLY );

// Load the updated drawable to the image viewer
imgStatus.setImageDrawable(d);
```

Comment: Will this process apply color only to the traced points(only over alphabet A) or anywhere in the image view. I need to color up only the traced points intersecting with the letter A.